# Is it possible to assert there are only duplicates with an AbstractIterableAssert?

Tags: java, testing, assertj

I have something like this:

```
assertThat(someList).extracting("someField")
```

and I want to continue the assert with asserting that only duplicates exist in the extraction. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: So assert that all elements of a list are the same?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca exactly

Comment: `list.size() > 1 && new HashSet<>(list).size() == 1`.

Comment: @AndyTurner I rephrased my question.

Comment: @HansWurst I don't know AssertJ, so I can't say exactly how to do it. First, assert that the list isn't empty; then, separately, assert that the size of `new HashSet<>(list)` is 1.

Comment: @AndyTurner this is definitely an option but I'm specifically interested in a solution using the AssertJ API. There is e.g. a method `doesNotContainDuplicates`

Comment: @HansWurst I don't think your requirement is common enough to expect such a method to exist.

Answer (score 1):

If you know what value is expected, [`containsOnly`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#containsOnly(ELEMENT...)) could be an option:

> Verifies that the actual group contains only the given values and nothing else, in any order and ignoring duplicates (i.e. once a value is found, its duplicates are also considered found).

Extending your example:

```
List<SomeObject> someList = List.of(
  new SomeObject("someValue"),
  new SomeObject("someValue")
);

assertThat(someList)
  .extracting("someField")
  .containsOnly("someValue");
```